# Referencing Mongoid recursively_embeds_many from another Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two Document Models that are proving problematic:

```
class Component
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning

  recursively_embeds_many
end

class Institution
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :components
end
```

I understand that you shouldn't be able to reference an embedded model from another document. I'm hoping however that with the recursively embedded documents there's a way to reference the top of the tree from another document? If this is not possible to use these relationships together at all, what alternatives do I have to setup a one-to-many relationship between Institution and Component while maintaining the recursive nature of component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do sounds reasonable but Mongoid won't let you associate a class that can be embedded with another class via an association. When I gave it a try I got an exception raised in [this file](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb) (line 218) when adding a (top-level) Component to an Institution.

The simplest option for you would be to embed Component in Institution, e.g.

```
class Institution
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :components
end
```

Otherwise, if you want to share Component trees with different Institutions I guess you would need to introduce some kind of container object into the model and define a many-many association to Institution, e.g.:

```
class Component
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning

  recursively_embeds_many
end

class ComponentTree
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :components
  has_and_belongs_to_many :institutions
end

class Institution
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :component_trees
end
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've done. It's not that conceptually components don't belong embedded in Institution, it's that there will be MANY of them for each institution and they'll be nested quite deeply, don't want to even have to think about the document size limit either.

Comment: Ah yes the document size limit often seems to be a factor in embedded documents. Although the limit on document size has gone up recently from 4 to 16MB the practical limit may be much lower from a performance point of view.